# Variation of the trading range

Tags: variance, indicator, asset, technicals, characteristic-function

Example: The trading range (in points) for each of the last 5 trading days for asset A is: **5,21,2,15,32** and for asset B is: **5,6,5,5,5**. Is there an ***indicator*** that ranks assets based on ***variation*** of trading ranges over a certain time period? (I don’t mean average).

*P.S: Not for predictive purposes, just to identify historical characteristics of certain assets.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could consider the *quadratic variation* of the asset price paths to indicate trading range. By quadratic variation, I make reference to the mathematics used in Stochastic Calculus, which is compute path-by-path (Steven E. Shreve, 2008).

$[M,M]_k=\sum^{k}_{j=1}{(M_j-M_{j-1})^2}$

Using your example above, Asset A variation is calculated as 1075 whereas Asset B variation is 2.

```
import numpy as np

# Quadratic Variation
quadratic_variation = lambda x: np.square(x[:-1]-x[1:]).sum()

asset_A = np.array([5,21,2,15,32])
asset_B = np.array([5,6,5,5,5])

variation_A = quadratic_variation(asset_A)
variation_B = quadratic_variation(asset_B)

print(variation_A,variation_B)
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Yes, but what I asked about is variation of given ranges. An indicator that would show me that asset B have a more consistent daily range value of 5, so the variation is almost to zero. Asset A has a large variation in each day range, so it’s variation would be far from zero. @ASX Portfolio

Comment: With that same example in my question, the ATR would give me a value of around 5(in points) for asset B and that’s not what I am looking for. Instead I expect an answer close to 0(in points).

Comment: Another example: Asset C has the following weekly trading ranges for each of the last 5 weeks as: week1: 10pips, week2: 10.5pips, week3: 10pips, week4: 9.5pips, week5: 10pips. If I was to use the ATR, the indicator would show me 10pips because that is the average range over the last 5 weeks. Instead I expect the indicator to show a value of approximately 0pips, because there is almost no variations in trading range. I apologize if my initial question was not clear enough. I believe it’s clear now, right? @ASX Portfolio

Comment: @immediate_blood hopefully my ammended answer helps.

Comment: Thanks. It did.

Comment: Do you have any idea if such an indicator is already available on any trading platform? @ASX Portfolio

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t think you’ll find it on popular retail brokerage platforms like Interactive Brokers, I encourage you to make your own - @immediate_blood

Comment: Alright, will try to do so. @ASX Portfolio